# If $e$ and $f$ are edges of a same vertex in an eulerian graph then there's an eulerian path where $e$ and $f$ are consecutives

Tags: graph-theory

I'm asked to prove or provide a counter-example for the following affirmation:

If $e$ and $f$ are edges of a same vertex in an eulerian graph then there's an eulerian path in the graph where $e$ and $f$ are consecutives.

First I tried finding a counter-example because I didn't think it was true. After some time drawing graphs and not having any success I went ahead and tried to formulate a proof that it was true, but wasn't able to get anywhere.

Can someone help me in any way?

Comment: Try the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph).

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now. Thank you very much.